# How can i get error message in form:errors tag by using MultiActionController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form:

```
<form:form commandName="command" method="post">
    <form:errors path="property"/>
    // some fields
</form:form>
```

And a MultiActionController

```
Command command = new Command();
ServletRequestDataBinder binder = createBinder(request, command);
binder.bind(request);

for (Validator validator: getValidators())
    if(validator.supports(command.getClass()))
        validator.validate(command, binder.getBindingResult());

if(binder.getBindingResult().hasErrors())
    // What to put here in order to show error message in <form:errors path="property"/>
```

I have used:

```
return new ModelAndView()
                     .addObject(binder.getBindingResult().getModel()) 
                     .addObject("command", command);
```

But it does not work. When the form is shown again (after a failure) the command properties are shown but error messages are not.

**ANSWER**

instead of

```
return new ModelAndView()
                     .addObject(binder.getBindingResult().getModel()) 
                     .addObject("command", command);
```

I have to call

```
return new ModelAndView()
                     .addAllObjects(binder.getBindingResult().getModel());
```

Notice **addAllObjects**. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Umm... it's too late at this point.

`binder.getBindingResult()` is an instance of [BindingResult](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) which is a subclass of [Errors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html). Errors produced by both your `bind()` method invocation and your validators have already been added to that `BindingResult` instance.

If some of them happened to be associated with `property` path you'll see them in output of `<form:errors>`, otherwise you won't. You could, of course, iterate through them and re-add them back with the path in question but what would be the point?

Comment: Take care is a MultiActionController

Comment: Chss, when i call binder.bind Validators is not called. I have used a logger inside it. When i call validator logger prints to output.

Comment: `bind()` is not going to invoke validators for you but you do (your code above looks fine). My point is that you're not likely to see anything as a result of `<form:errors path="property"/>` unless either bind fails for it (does it?) or one of the validators explicitly specifies that as path (does it?) Did you try leaving 'path' out altogether to see all the errors?

Comment: Hi Chss, code is right. See additional comment in my question

Comment: binder.bind(request); does not performs validation. I take a look at source code.